# Who is Administrator of MySQL schema?

Tags: mysql, database

A quick question:

I want to know what is admin UID of the MySQL DB schema I am using. Is there any way I can query for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a notion of "schema administrator" in MySQL. The administrative privilege ([`SUPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html)) can be granted at instance level only.

You can list users having this privilege by querying the `mysql` system schema:

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE Super_priv = 'Y';
```

All privileges can be checked (or modified manually) through the tables from this schema. See [the manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant-table-structure.html) for a complete listing.

For example, to list users who can create a table in schema "myschema":

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.db WHERE Create_priv = 'Y' AND Db = 'myschema';
```